# Change Varchar to Time type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In the table I have a field (Varchar) called CallTime.

It includes the times such as 8:00 PM, 8:40 PM, 10:00 AM

I want to change the field type to Time and update time format.. how can that be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name SET CallTimeNew = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CallTime,'%l:%i %p'), '%H:%i:%s');
```

or just change the column type as other user suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in the following steps:

- Create a Time type column named CallTimeNew;
- Write a script that takes the values from CallTime, convert it to time using `mktime()` and the friends, and write it to CallTimeNew;
- Remove the CallTime column and rename the CallTimeNew column to CallTime

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL I could just change the field type from varchar to time, and it automatically changed the format from 1:30 PM to 01:30:00.

Otherwise you can write a small PHP script to loop through all times, format them with date and strtotime, and then insert them back in a correct format before you switch field types.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ALTER COLUMN Time DATETIME NULL;
```